# why more than one function not call to WCF?

Tags: jquery, wcf

I am passing the Value to Array Element in WCF service. Here I am Using jQuery.

My functions are:

In Service.cs:

```
public class User
{

    Dictionary<int, string> users = null;
    public User()
    {
        users = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        users.Add(1, "apple");
        users.Add(2, "orange");
        users.Add(3, "lemon");
        users.Add(4, "grape");
    }

    public string[] GetUser(int Id)
    {
        var user = from u in users
                   where u.Key == Id
                   select u.Value;

        return user.ToArray<string>();
    }
```

In jQuery:

```
function CallService() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: Type, 
                 url: Url, 
                 data: Data, 
                 contentType: ContentType,
                 dataType: DataType, 
                 processdata: ProcessData, 
                 success: function(msg) {
                     ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                 },
                 error: ServiceFailed
             });
         }
```

My first function I declare like this:

```
 function WCFJSON() {

             var uesrid = "2";
             Type = "POST";
             Url = "Service.svc/GetUser";
             Data = '{"Id": "' + uesrid + '"}';
             ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
             DataType = "json"; ProcessData = true; 

             CallService();

         }
```

This function I called like below:

```
 $(document).ready(
         function() {
         WCFJSON();
         }
         );
```

My second function is:

```
function temp()
         {
         //var id=parseInt($('#txtinput').val();
         var id="5";
         Type="POST";
         Url="Srvice.svc/GetUser";
         Data='{"Id":"'+id+'"}';
         ContentType="application/json;charset=utf-8";
         DataType="json";ProcessData=true;
        CallService();

         }
```

I called this function by button onclient click, like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsumbit" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClientClick ="temp();"  />
```

My problem is when I ran this program, I got only got a result from first function ("WCFJSON();"), other function of "temp();" I didn't get any result. I don't know what I am missing? Can anyone resolve this?

Comment: Is the typo in `Srvice.svc` present in your original code?

Comment: you not call `temp()` function, and also, what is `CallService()` ?

Comment: you use global namespace to pass argument to `CallService()` ?

Comment: the html rendered correct ? where the jquery code here ?

Comment: Please put a better title on your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]    Data = '{"Id": "' + uesrid + '"}';

should be:

```
Data = {"Id": uesrid};
```

This is supposed to be an object, and `$.ajax` will serialize it.

In temp(), change:

```
Data='{"Id":"'+id+'"}';
```

to:

```
Data={"Id": id };
```

Comment: Service call Failed:500Internal server Error

Comment: You need to check the errors on the server to see why it isn't working.

Comment: when i running my program with your code-its throws 400:Bad request,

Comment: at the same time if i do replace your code its not throw any error

Comment: i will show that error message image,it will be helpful to find what happens.

Comment: Never mind, I just noticed that you set contentType=application/json, so your version was correct.

Comment: But it would probably be better to use `JSON.stringify` instead of constructing the string yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17969/discussion-between-ananth-s-and-barmar)